# How do I hide the search box on the jquery-bootgrid table?

Tags: jquery

I can't find an option to hide the search box.

Is there an option ?

Should I be doing that by setting the class to hidden via Javascript?

Thanks,
F

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution but you can add an empty string for the search template

```
$(...).bootgrid({
    // ...
    templates: {
        search: ""
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I guess the Andreas answer is better for you, but also you can override the header of your table with the:

```
$("#grid").bootgrid({
    templates: {
        header: "<your header>"    
    }
});
```

More explanations are here: https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-bootgrid/issues/82

So the default header template is:

```
header: "<div id=\"{{ctx.id}}\" class=\"{{css.header}}\">
<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-sm-12 actionBar\"><p class=\"
{{css.search}}\"></p><p class=\"{{css.actions}}\"></p></div></div></div>"
```

You can find it in the source code where all default templates are defined (it is about 1210 row number of the `jquery.bootgrid.js` file).

In your case you just need to take original header, override it in your bootgrid settings and there hide or remove (if you need) or set the extra id or css class to the: `<p class=\"{{css.search}}\"></p>`.

Answer (score 4):

While the previous answers will work, there is a method to hide the header and footer elements such as the search bar built in to Bootgrid. From the Bootgrid documentation:

[image]

You would use it like this:

```js
$("#example-table").bootgrid({
    selection: true,
    rowCount: -1,
    rowSelect : true,
    navigation: 0
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code works

```
.bootgrid-header .actionBar .actions{ display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would LIKE to do it via jQuery you can do `$('.search').hide();` or add a class like you had asked.

If you would like the search element hidden when the document is done loading you would...

```
$(function(){
 $('.search').addClass('hidden');
});
```

and then in your css...

```
.hidden { display: none }
```

You may instead want to hide it in your stylesheet with `.search ( display: none }`

This approach would prevent having the search show until the jQuery hides it, and would be easier for the next developer to understand.

After searching briefly through the online docs (http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation), I did not see anything to hide this feature built into the script.

Good luck (tested this in the console, it worked fine)